# Bazel binary location not found in android studio by using wsl

Tags: android-studio, installation, bazel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed the Bazel on the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) for MediaPipe. When I open Bazel project in android studio it does not build, it gives a sync error. I think a specific Bazel binary location is not found.

I tried almost all the methods that I get from Google. I also tried all the file which is under Bazel folder, but it gives the same error.

> Error:Cannot run program "/usr/local/bazel/0.27.0/lib/bazel/bin/bazel"
> (in directory
> "C:\Users\BHARGAV\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\ubuntu\mediapipe"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified